# How to find an element from protractor filter result

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I have the following angular snippet

```
<ul class="nav" ng-repeat="website in licensedWebsitesList">
    <li>
         <blockquote class="blockquote-small">
             <p>{{website.websiteIdentifier}}</p>
              <p>
                  <a href="#" ui-sref="^.licensed-website-edit({licensedWebsiteId: website.id})" class="btn green-haze licensed-website-edit">Edit</a>

              </p>
         </blockquote>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to do is find a particular element and edit it in a protractor test. This is what I have tried:

```
var websites = element.all(by.repeater('website in licensedWebsitesList'));

websites.filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.element(by.binding('website.websiteIdentifier')).getText().then(function(text) {
          return text === 'new website identifier';
        });
      }).then(function(filterElements) {
           filterElements.getElementByClassName('licensed-website-edit')[0].click();
     });
browser.sleep(1000);
//code to enter details into the form opened by clicking the edit button above
```

The above code throws the error:

```
Object  has no method 'getElementByClassName'
```

I also tried:

```
websites.filter(function(elem, index) {
          return elem.element(by.binding('website.websiteIdentifier')).getText().then(function(text) {
              return text === 'new website identifier';
            });
          }).then(function(filterElements) {
               //try 1 failed
               filterElements.element(by.className('licensed-website-edit')).click();
               //replaced above one with this which also failed
               filterElements[0].element(by.className('licensed-website-edit')).click();
         });
```

Then I also tried:

```
websites.filter(function(elem, index) {
          return elem.element(by.binding('website.websiteIdentifier')).getText().then(function(text) {
              return text === 'new website identifier';
            });
          }).element(by.className('licensed-website-edit')).click();
```

which also failed saying:

> [object object] has no method element

I need to click the edit button for the case where the repeater has the identifier text i am looking for. Any help welcome.

Comment: can you try filterElements[0].$('.licensed-website-edit').click(); ?

Comment: I will try and see if it works

Comment: filterElements[0].element(by.css('.licensed-website-edit')).click();